# Marshmallow storage permission is executing only once

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

In my application I am requesting storage permission, my issue is for the time while I launch application if I deny the permission I am showing the alert dialog and closing the application, again if I enter the application I want the permission popup to arise again but I am not getting the popup instead my app is staying blank white screen.

Comment: post your code when you first time ask for permission

Comment: and you shouldn't close the application , just redirect the user to app settings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow this will help you

Comment: our application need is to close the application for the first time when the user denied and next time the user application reenters again it should start from the permission